# Is there a Ansible function to convert date string to epoch?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am looking to convert date input variable into epoch. I did not see a Ansible function to help me with this.

For eg:

Date is a variable of format: `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`, this needs to be converted to epoch secs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ansible has a `to_datetime` filter, documented [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).  That page includes the following examples:

> ```
> # Get total amount of seconds between two dates. Default date format is %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S but you can pass your own format
> {{ (("2016-08-14 20:00:12" | to_datetime) - ("2015-12-25" | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).total_seconds()  }}
>
> # Get remaining seconds after delta has been calculated. NOTE: This does NOT convert years, days, hours, etc to seconds. For that, use total_seconds()
> {{ (("2016-08-14 20:00:12" | to_datetime) - ("2016-08-14 18:00:00" | to_datetime)).seconds  }}
> # This expression evaluates to "12" and not "132". Delta is 2 hours, 12 seconds
>
> # get amount of days between two dates. This returns only number of days and discards remaining hours, minutes, and seconds
> {{ (("2016-08-14 20:00:12" | to_datetime) - ("2015-12-25" | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).days  }}
> ```

Using this filter, you could convert a date to string to a unix epoch time like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ('2019-05-06 15:50:00'|to_datetime).strftime('%s') }}"
```

Which would output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "1557172200"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to convert a string for the user module. The other approaches her didn't work for me.

You can use `strftime`:

vars:

```
expire_date: 2020-07-12
```

task:

```
- name: "create user"
  user:
    name: user
    expires: "{{ expire_date.strftime('%s') }}"
  become: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following to get a date stored from a previous call (e.g. 2020-03-10) converted.

```
msg: "{{ ((variable.stdout + ' 00:00:00') | to_datetime).strftime('%s') }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, that worked. here is what i am doing

```
- name: update blackout file
  win_lineinfile:
    path: D:\temp\blackout\blackout.txt
    backup: yes
    insertafter: EOF
    line: "\\r\\nPermissions: admin=write\\r\\nadhoc:{{ regex_suppression }};{{ start_date_epoch }};{{ end_date_epoch }};{{ changerequest }}"
  vars:
    regex_suppression: "^(?i).*__({{serverlist | regex_replace(',','|')}}).*"
    start_date_epoch:  "{{ ( start_time | to_datetime).strftime('%s') }}"
    end_date_epoch:    "{{ ( end_time | to_datetime).strftime('%s') }}"
```