# Ansible convert "2024-02-26T15:47:06.403633+00:00" to epoch

Tags: datetime, ansible

Just like the title says, I'm struggling to convert `2024-02-26T15:47:06.403633+00:00` to epoch. Here is what I have so far:

```
{{ '2024-02-26T15:47:06.403633+00:00'| to_datetime(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z') | strftime('%s') }}
```

But it throws the error:

```
Invalid value for epoch value (%s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `strftime('%s')` incorrectly, try this:

```
{{ ('2024-02-26T15:47:06.403633+00:00' | to_datetime(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')).strftime('%s') }}
```

[Is there a Ansible function to convert date string to epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56010395/is-there-a-ansible-function-to-convert-date-string-to-epoch)